# Package javax.smartcardio as an OSGI Bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

I am building an Karaf OSGI application which uses javax.smartcardio library. when I deploy it, it is giving me the following error:

```
Unable to resolve 249.0: missing requirement [249.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.smartcardio)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:488)[26:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:402)[26:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.2]
    at Proxy532dee57_5493_41af_a3a1_bf689277fb5b.installFeature(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar.KarArtifactInstaller.installFeatures(KarArtifactInstaller.java:189)[24:org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar.KarArtifactInstaller.install(KarArtifactInstaller.java:134)[24:org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.install(DirectoryWatcher.java:929)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.install(DirectoryWatcher.java:857)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:483)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[6:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.2.6]
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.isirona.drivers.neuroptics-npi200.core [249]: Unable to resolve 249.0: missing requirement [249.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.smartcardio)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:931)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:485)[26:org.apache.karaf.features.core:2.3.2]
```

I want to package javax.smartcardio library as a bundle. There are links on how to build a bundle from .jar but I cannot find javax.smartcardio library in my JDK.

Is it inside the JDK? Do I have to do anything special to get access to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's part of the JDK make sure you export it as a system package. 
For this edit the *etc/jre.properties* file.

You'll need to add the corresponding package to the section of the JVM you use. And usually it's also best to export it with a correct version if known.